# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^ \infty n! z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

This is a question from Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis. My idea is that the series shouldn't converge anywhere, since any disc will contain a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$. Since $n!$ eventually grows faster than $q^n$ the sum should blow up. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: What about $z=0$? Your reasoning for the other discs is correct.

Comment: $\frac {|a_{n+1}|} {|a_n|} \to \infty$ if $z \neq 0$. So the series converges only for $z=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We look at the general term of this series and so we go ahead and attempt to use the ratio test. We thus compute $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \vert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\vert$. We thus have $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \vert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\vert=\lim_{n\to \infty} \vert \frac{(n+1)!z^{n+1}}{n!z^n}\vert $, and this in turn simplies to $\lim_{n\to \infty} (n+1) \vert z\vert= \vert z\vert \lim_{n\to \infty} n+1= \infty$.

So by the ratio test $\rho =\infty >1$ hence no matter what $z$ is the series diverges! Except there is one little detail here is that every power series has at least one element in its domain: the center. The center in this case is $z=0$ and this is the only place where we have convergence. The radius of convergence is thus $R=0$.

The power series only converges at $z=0$ because $S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n!z^n = 1+z+2!z^2+3!z^3+...$ and at $z=0$ we obtain $S=1$.